# How to concat two array in one with this data? JS

Tags: javascript, loops

I need to concat two arrays.
First Array is an array of descriptions

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the arrays are always of equal length... you can use the second argument passed to the callback function(which is the index of each element) for accessing the elements of the other array.

```js
const description = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

const allPictures = ['url-1', 'url-2', 'url-3'];

const result = description.map((des, index) => ({
  url: allPictures[index],
  description: des
}));

console.log(result);
```

If you don't want to create an object when either of the arrays has falsy values:

```js
const descriptions = ['One', '', 'Three', undefined];

const allPictures = ['url-1', 'url-2', null, ''];

const result = descriptions.reduce((acc,description, index) => {
  const url = allPictures[index];
  if(description && url) {
    acc.push({ description, url });
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Okey but how to remove item-object if is value "" or null ?

Comment: I want to push only object with values

Comment: @wamovec So, does your array contain falsy values? Update your question.

Comment: @wamovec Updated my answer... maybe that's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Make sure both arrays are equal in size.
```

```js
const description = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
const allPictures = ['url-1', 'url-2', 'url-3'];

const imageObject = description.map((item, index) => {
  return {
    url: item,
    description: allPictures[index]
  }
})


console.log('imageObject', imageObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard for loop

```js
const allPictures = ['url-1', 'url-2', 'url-3'];
const description = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < allPictures.length; i++) {
  result.push({
    url: allPictures[i],
    description: description[i]
  });
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple with array's map function

1. keep track on index, you'll use it to know the index of an element so as you can choose its corresponding element on another array
   as below

   const mergedArray = allPictures.map((url,index) => {

   ```
        return { url : url,
             description : description[index]
           }
     })
   ```